# dynamic select with ajax php and mariadb

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am triying to do a dynamic select using ajax, php and querys to a BBDD.
For this reason I have three parts, the html where I populated my options of selects with the consults that I am doing to the BBDD, this consult is realised with AJAX and the scripts to consult BBDD is do it in php.
My html is the following:

```
<div class="student-data-block">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>Nombre</label>
                            <input type="text" name="name" value="" placeholder=""/>
                            <br/>
                            <label>Apellido</label>
                            <input type="text" name="last_name" value="" placeholder=""/>
                            <br/>
                            <label>Universidad</label>
                            <select name="universitySelect" id="universitySelect" value="" placeholder="">
                                <option value="">Escoger universidad</option>
                                <?php foreach ($universities as $name) { ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $name['UniversityID']?>"><?php echo $name['UniversityName']?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label>Campus</label>
                            <select name="campusSelect" id="campusSelect" value="" placeholder="">
                                <option value="">Escoger campus</option>
                            </select>
                            <br/>
                            <label>Carrera</label>
                            <select name="careerSelect" id="careerSelect" value="" placeholder="">
                                <option value="">Escoger carrera</option>
                            </select>
                            <br/>
                            <label>Nivel académico</label>
                            <select name="study_type" value=""
                                    placeholder="">
                                <option value="grado">Escoger nivel académico</option>
                                <option value="grado">Grado</option>
                                <option value="master">Máster</option>
                                <option value="postgrado">Postgrado</option>
                                <option value="doctorado">Doctorado</option>
                            </select>
                            <br/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

First we consult the BBDD and populate the first select, the #universitySelect, after to populate the followings selects I need the option choosen for the user, to populate the others select in function to the option choosen. To build the followings we use Ajax, exactly this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#universitySelect').change(function() {
            var universityID = $("#universitySelect").val();
            if (universityID) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'action/AjaxSelect.php',
                    data: 'universityID=' + universityID,
                    success: function (html) {
                        $('#campusSelect').html(html);
                        $('#careerSelect').html('<option value="">Selecciona tu carrera</option>');
                    }
                });
            } else {
                $('#campusSelect').html('<option value="">Selecciona tu campus primero</option>');
                $('#careerSelect').html('<option value="">Selecciona tu carrera primero</option>');
            }
        });
        $('#campusSelect').change(function(){
                var campusID = $("#campusSelect").val();
                if (campusID) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'action/AjaxSelect.php',
                        data: 'campusID=' + campusID,
                        success: function (html) {
                            $('#careerSelect').html(html);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $('#careerSelect').html('<option value="">Selecciona tu carrera primero</option>');
                }
            });
    }   );
```

Finally when I receive the data of the AJAX I consult the BBDD to populate the others select. My AjaxSelect.php is the following:

```
    if(!empty($_REQUEST["universityID"])){ //&& isset($_REQUEST["universityID"])
    $q_campus = 'select c.CampusID, c.Name as CareerName from unithinks.campus c
              where UniversityID="$_REQUEST["universityID"]" order by c.CampusID asc ';

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCampus = query($db_connection, $q_campus);

    //State option list
    if($rowCampus > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Selecciona campus</option>';
        foreach ($rowCampus as $campus){
            echo '<option value="'.$campus['CampusID'].'">'.$campus['CareerName'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Selecciona primero universidad</option>';
    }
}
else if(!empty($_REQUEST["campusID"])){
    $q_careers = 'select ca.CareerID, ca.Name as CareerName from unithinks.careers ca
              where CampusID = "$_REQUEST["campusID"]" order by ca.CareerID asc ';
    $rowCareers = query($db_connection, $q_campus);

    //State option list
    if($rowCareers > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Selecciona Carrera</option>';
        foreach ($rowCareers as $careers){
            echo '<option value="'.$careers['CampusID'].'">'.$careers['CareerName'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Selecciona primero universidad o campus</option>';
    }
```

I don't see where is the error. I know that the code function well until arrive at ajax petition, in the Ajax I don't know to see if it is sending the POST.
(Also, explain that the consult return the data well.).

Sorry, I am new using php. 
Thanks tou in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate more clear what your problem is. What do you expect? And what do you get instead? Please review our [SO Question Checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Comment out all your script in AjaxSelect.php and simply put <?php var_dump($_POST); ?>. In your ajax success: function (html) { console.log(html);}; and see what you get

Comment: I have edit my comment and explain more accuratly my problem.

Comment: Hi Michael I see in the console.log: error 404. The AJAX doesn't found the action/AjaxSelect.php file. 
This is the problem, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the url of the AJAX and in the consult of the BDD.

The code is the following:

```
$('#universitySelect').change(function() {
            var universityID = $("#universitySelect").val();
            //alert(universityID);
            if (universityID) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'actions/AjaxSelect.php',
                    data: 'universityID=' + universityID,
                    success: function (html)
                        {
                            console.log(html);
                        $('#campusSelect').html(html);
                        $('#careerSelect').html('<option value="">Selecciona tu carrera</option>');
                        }
                });
            } else {
                $('#campusSelect').html('<option value="">Selecciona tu campus primero</option>');
                $('#careerSelect').html('<option value="">Selecciona tu carrera primero</option>');
            }
        });
```

and ajaxSelect.php:

```
$db_connection = Connect_MySqli($cnn);   
if(!empty($_REQUEST["universityID"])){ //&& isset($_REQUEST["universityID"])
    $q_campus = 'select c.CampusID, c.Name as CareerName from unithinks.campus c
              where UniversityID='.$_REQUEST["universityID"].' order by c.CampusID asc ';

    //Count total number of rows
    $rowCampus = query($db_connection, $q_campus);
    //State option list
    if($rowCampus > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Selecciona campus</option>';
        foreach ($rowCampus as $campus){
            echo '<option value="'.$campus['CampusID'].'">'.$campus['CareerName'].'</option>';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<option value="">Selecciona primero universidad</option>';
    }
}
```